# How to remove 'renv' folder? Cannot access project so cannot use renv::deactivate

Tags: r, project, renv, rprofile

I'm trying to remove the 'renv' folder from my project, in order to remove renv from the project.

**Note: I cannot access the project on the server that I'm on**, so trying to do this from file explorer.

I have managed to

- remove the renv.lock file
- remove the "source("renv/activate.R")" from the .Rprofile file

I have then tried to delete the 'renv' folder from my project, but it won't delete.

Any help or other ideas appreciated!